# gaps and island with extra condition (SQL server)

Tags: sql-server, ssms, gaps-and-islands

I have a table showing the first three columns for each member:
The date column includes 365 dates for multiple years, they are consecutive. The service columns shows numbers of services they received. I would like to add the GroupDate column to it. Every time there's a service, it would trigger the GroupDate to start counting 1, and it will last 5 consecutive days. And I want to name it using the beginning of the group date. When it ends on day 5, it would look for the next date that the member has a service, and it would start counting 5 consecutive days again.

| Member | Date | Service | GroupDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | 1/1 | 1 | 1/1 |
| Mary | 1/2 | 2 | 1/1 |
| Mary | 1/3 | 0 | 1/1 |
| Mary | 1/4 | 1 | 1/1 |
| Mary | 1/5 | 0 | 1/1 |
| Mary | 1/6 | 0 | NA |
| Mary | 1/7 | 0 | NA |
| Mary | 1/8 | 1 | 1/8 |
| Mary | 1/9 | 1 | 1/8 |
| Mary | 1/10 | 1 | 1/8 |
| Mary | 1/11 | 0 | 1/8 |
| Mary | 1/12 | 2 | 1/8 |
| Mary | 1/13 | 1 | 1/13 |
| Mary | 1/14 | 0 | 1/13 |
| Mary | 1/15 | 0 | 1/13 |
| Mary | 1/16 | 0 | 1/13 |
| Mary | 1/17 | 0 | 1/13 |

Comment: SSMS is used to connect to several different products such as (but not limited to), SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure SQL Database. What Database Product, and version, are you using? I doubt SSMS is actually relevant to the question here.

Comment: Thanks! It's for SQL server v 18. I just made an edit.

Comment: Version 18 isn't out yet, Pumpkin, we only got version 16 (2022) towards the end of last year. Version 18 probably won't be out till around 2026.

Comment: sorry! it's v15